# How can I use DropDown List in Expo React-Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have been facing a problem with react native and expo as I cannot find a dropdown list component for  form input. How can I do that without ejecting from expo?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Picker module](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/picker/). They recommend using the React Native Community Picker package. You do not need to eject for it to work, you can just install it through NPM.

Comment: React native picker package doesn't make sense to me. It's like a scrollable list embedded in place. Not one that opens on a click or touch like a drop-down or select list. Really seems kind of half-baked and weird that they suggest that, after deprecating the perfectly fine one that they had before

Answer (score 1):

I tried many react-native and expo dropdowns. But the best one is `react-native-material-dropdown-v2-fixed` that I ever found. So I was thinking I should have to share with all you guys.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-dropdown-v2-fixed

Answer (score 0):

try this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-picker
On others expo versions the picker from react has being depreciated so on this link you'll find different examples of drop down listings.

Answer (score 0):

Try ListItem from React Native Elements:
https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/listitem

See ListItem.Accordion example.